# java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError for CompletableFuture after Java update to 17 version

Tags: java, heroku, reflection, completable-future, java-17

I have updated the Java version of our company application from 8 to 17.
On local machine it works fine, both in building and on run-time calls.
Also on GitHub it is deployed fine, along with the Junit test execution.

The problem is after I deploy the application on Heroku.
The Heroku build is on success, but on runtime, when I call the methods, I receive this error:

```
"message": "Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError: Signature Parse error: expected a class type\n\tRemaining input: java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture",
```

It's something related to java reflection methods and the method's signature.
My controller rest method return a CompletableFuture Object.
Something is not good with the CompletableFuture.........

Comment: Could you provide the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: This is the only message I have.
I receive this message calling a rest controller with Postman.
I have the message only in dev environment, not on local environment.
The problem was related to CompletableFuture Instrumentation on New Relic.
I need to deactivate it, and now the app works

Answer (score 5):

This error relates to [this bug](https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-java-agent/issues/526), which is being investigating.

Currently the workaround is to disable CompletableFuture instrumentation.
That can be done by adding the following to your newrelic.yml, under the common stanza:

```
  class_transformer:
    com.newrelic.instrumentation.java.completable-future-jdk8u40:
      enabled: false
```

Update 2022-02-23: The bug in New Relic was caused by this bug in Java 17: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8282241

Update 2022-07-29: Java 19 early releases already contains a fix. Should be fixed in Java 17.0.5, to be released in Oct 2022.

Update 2022-10-19: Java 17.0.5 has been released with the fix to the bug that caused this issue.