# Disabling CompletableFuture Instrumentation into New Relic Configuration

Tags: newrelic, completable-future, java-17

There is a problem in Java17 related to CompletableFuture Instrumentation.
In oder to make my application run, I have disabled it.
I have added the following lines to the newrelic.yml :

```
 class_transformer:
    com.newrelic.instrumentation.java.completable-future-jdk8u40:
      enabled: false
```

It seems that on New relic nothing has changed.
Because of my ignorance I do not know what exactly this might entail.

Do I risk to have some problem when we`ll deply our application in production?

Comment: What’s the relevance of the (very specific) version number “jdk8u40” in this configuration line that is obviously entirely unrelated to the JDK 17 you’re using? And how are we supposed to judge the risks associated with a problem that has been described as detailed as “there is a problem”?

Comment: @Holger The problem I had was this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69943595/java-lang-reflect-genericsignatureformaterror-for-completablefuture-after-java-u?noredirect=1#comment123763484_69943595

Comment: @Holger the `jdk8u40` refers to the first version for which that instrumentation module works. There is another module for CompletableFuture prior to that update that is named `java.completable-future-jdk8`.

Answer (score 0):

That instrumentation module links the execution of the CompletableFuture to the original request.

Much of what the New Relic agent does is linked to the thread that started the request and when that thread starts another one, they have to be linked.

Disabling the module will prevent this linking and since the execution of the Future is not linked to a New Relic transaction, nothing in it will be tracked. Which means the existing transaction will not contain the execution of that CompletableFuture. Errors occurring there will not be reported....

To maintain visibility, you'll need to add custom instrumentation using the async API.

Basically you'll have to [add the New Relic API as a dependency](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.newrelic.agent.java/newrelic-api/7.4.0/jar) to your project.

Then in the main thread [create a Token and use it](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/java-agent/async-instrumentation/java-agent-api-asynchronous-applications/#tokens) on the other thread to link them.

There is a [ticket](https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-java-agent/issues/526) in the repo about this bug.